# pg_dump blocking Postgres database access with same user

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump, database-locking

We have a Django application running on Ubuntu using a Postgres DB on the same server. We are backing up our database every day with the following command:

```
pg_dump -Fc -U user1 -w db_name > ${filepath}`
```

The problem is that is seems to be blocking read/write access to the same database with the same user (`user1`) no our Django app. Checking the documentation it states that

> pg_dump does not block other users accessing the database (readers or
>   writers)

Which makes me think that maybe is it blocking access to the DB because the Django app is using the same user. Can this happen? I didn't find any documentation that clarifies it.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?  Are there errors connecting, which might imply max_connections or the connection limit of the user is too low or are you seeing the queries being blocked by pg_dump?  If the latter, check pg_stat_statements to verify that your queries are waiting.

Answer (score 4):

If access is actually *blocked*, i.e. you get no error, but the application hangs, it must be that the application takes `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks on tables.

That can happen if your workload has a lot of `TRUNCATE` or `ALTER TABLE` statements or similar. Those would be blocked until `pg_dump`, which runs in a single transaction for consistency, is done.

It could also be explicit table locks taken with `LOCK tablename`, which are usually a sign of bad design.

Try to reduce the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks in your workload, they can also [prevent autovacuum and thus damage your database](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/lock-table-can-harm-your-database/).